# DFS on disconnected components.

Tags: graph-theory, searching

I was given the following graph. Does the DFS stop at c? So: a,b,d,c. or does it continue with the other component as well? I'm not sure on how it works with disconnected graphs but from what I read it stops at c and declares the graph to be disconnected. Just wanted to make sure I got it right.
But does it ignore the other component overall or does it start searching as it would with a new graph meaning with discovery time 1 again at e. What would be the discovery and finish time for the other component?

Thanks in advance. [image]

Comment: It depends on how you program the DFS, especially where you start the DFS, and whether you do DFS on each connected component. Often in code, you would keep performing DFS on nodes that haven't been reached yet, so here you might do DFS starting at a and DFS starting at e.